# Custom Route Not Working in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-routing

I have been trying to following this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202(v=vs.90).aspx

I have created add this to my web.config:

```
<modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
           type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
               System.Web.Routing, 
               Version=3.5.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
```

And, I have added this to my Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SplendidInit.InitApp();
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.Add("ShortUrl_Attachment_NoLogin", new Route
            (
               "a",
               new CustomRouteHandler("~/FACTS/Attachments/Attachment_NoLogin.aspx")
            ));
        }

        public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
        {
            public CustomRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
            {
                this.VirtualPath = virtualPath;
            }

            public string VirtualPath { get; private set; }

            public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext
                  requestContext)
            {
                var page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath
                     (VirtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IHttpHandler;
                return page;
            }
        }
```

When I navigate to `/FACTS/Attachments/Attachment_NoLogin.aspx` it works; but, when I try to navigate to my custom route `/a`, it says, "**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**."

How can I make my custom route work?

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

**I am using .NET 3.5, on IIS 7.5, if that makes a difference (which I assume it does).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was to just download and install the IIS Rewrite module.  It was super easy, and super cool :)

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite